# Transform response data with RxJS Operators in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-httpclient

I have a service response like below.

```
  "amount": 3330,
  "count": 56,
  "dataObjects": [
    {
      "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:4200/api/collection/"
      },
      "id": "W391",
      "objectNumber": "IN-W391",
      "title": "Image 23",
      "webImage": {
        "guid": "89de22aa-e19f-4c83-87ff-26dd8f319c05",
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 800,
        "url": "http://localhost:4200/api/collection/7qzT0pbclLB7y3fdS1GxzMnV7m3gD3gWnhlquhFaJSn6gNOvMmTUAX3wVlTzhMXIs8kM9IH8AsjHNVTs8em3XQI6uMY=s0"
      }
    },
    {
      "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:4200/api/collection/"
      },
      "id": "W391",
      "objectNumber": "IN-W391",
      "title": "Image 23",
      "webImage": {
        "guid": "89de22aa-e19f-4c83-87ff-26dd8f319c05",
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 800,
        "url": "http://localhost:4200/api/collection/7qzT0pbclLB7y3fdS1GxzMnV7m3gD3gWnhlquhFaJSn6gNOvMmTUAX3wVlTzhMXIs8kM9IH8AsjHNVTs8em3XQI6uMY=s0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All i am trying to do is to retrieve just the *dataObjects* array so that i can loop through it and bind the *url* under *webImage* and display it in the UI. here is what i have tried

**Component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.artistService.GetArtistDetails().pipe(map( response=> response.dataObjects))
    .subscribe((artists: any[])=>{
      console.log(artists);
    });  
  }
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
 public GetArtistDetails(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER);
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your service file, can you cast it directly to a model type? e.g. method GetArtistDetails(): Observable<DataObjects[]> { // then use .pipe(map(result=>result.dataObjects ))}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what A2Ia said, here is a sample code that works as desired:

stackblitz app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1ixvmx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

result: https://angular-ivy-1ixvmx.stackblitz.io